# TweenMax at function out - how to implement conditional?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gsap, scrollmagic

I'm using JS libraries: **GSAP** along with **ScrollMagic.io** by Jan Paepke.

Scrollmagic.io allows me to trigger some CSS changes on scrolling once certain trigger element is reached, the JS script looks like this:

```
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
                        var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
                                triggerElement: "#trigger1"
                            })
                            .setTween(new TimelineMax().add([
                                TweenMax.to("header", 0.5, {backgroundColor: "rgba(40,80,01, 0.95)", height:"6%", width:"100%", top:"0", borderRadius:"0px"}),
                                TweenMax.to(".headernav", 0.5, {color:"white", fontSize:"1.5em", marginTop:"10px"}),
                                TweenMax.to(".circle", 0.5, {height:"35px", marginTop:"10px"}),
                                TweenMax.to("#logo", 0.5, {width:"70px", marginTop:"-10px", marginRight:"500px"})
                            ]))
                            .addTo(controller);
```

In general - it would change position, background-color and font color of my menu once it is scrolled over white area of website so that it will still be noticable and easy to read.

The problem is my **a:hover** within menu stopped working.
I've found a workaround by using this:

```
$("#verticalnav p").hover(over, out);

     function over(){
          TweenMax.to(this, 0.5, {color:"rgb(181, 171, 171)", scale:"1.1"})
     }

     function out(){
          TweenMax.to(this, 0.5, {color:"rgb(105, 105, 105)", scale:"1"})
     }
```

This makes it work fine, but there's still one thing to be worked out - while background of menu is "white", color:"dimgray" of font is well noticable/readable, but it will also remain "dimgray" on the green background after scrolling.

**Here's screenshot explanation to show it more clearly:**

Default menu state with no hovers:
[image]

On:hover using js - changes color using script shown above:
[image]

Here some properties of menu have changed along with font color to be more readable on green background:
[image]

And here's how it looks like when the mouse is **OUT** of the link, leaving it "dimgray" because the script makes it:
[image]

My question is - how may I implement a conditional into this script:

```
$("#verticalnav p").hover(over, out);

 function over(){
      TweenMax.to(this, 0.5, {color:"rgb(181, 171, 171)", scale:"1.1"})
 }

 function out(){
      TweenMax.to(this, 0.5, {color:"rgb(105, 105, 105)", scale:"1"})
 }
```

so that it would read the current color value and run TweenMax.to with specific color according to this value?
I'm fairly green with JS so any kind of advice would be highly appreciated.

Regards,
Damian.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it seems that the longer I don't get answer, the more creative i become.

Already worker it out, pretty much basic JS/jQuery was needed, posting it so maybe somebody could have some use of it later on.
Here's working code of function hover:

```
                            $("#verticalnav p").hover(over, out);

                        function over(){
                          TweenMax.to(this, 0.5, {color:"rgb(181, 171, 171)", scale:"1.1"})
                        };

                        function out(){
                            var kolor = $("header").css("background-color");
                            if (kolor == "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.901961)") {
                          TweenMax.to(this, 0.5, {color:"rgb(105, 105, 105)", scale:"1"})
                          }
                            else {
                              TweenMax.to(this, 0.5, {color:"white", scale:"1"})  
                            }
                        };
```